# How to Implement touch on a hybrid app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a MFP 7.1 hybrid app . Can you give me some hints on how to implement touch (iOS and Android)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of materials online... try those first, and if you fail, ask an actual programming-related question.

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UbdcNx2Bzs
article: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/touchid_authentication_with_worklight?lang=en
Google: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=mobilefirst+touch+id&oq=mobilefirst+touch+id&aqs=chrome..69i57.3846j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8